# Data Under fitting and its handling

Tags: data-cleaning

Regularization is used to handle over-fitting problem.

Similarly can we have some methodology to overcome under fitting problem or merely adding new features or training data will help us in reducing under-fitting issue?

Comment: Why do you want to underfit? having better data, more features and modelling as per proper requirements

Comment: I dont want  to underfit, I just want to know the methods for handling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As such we don't have much ways to handle under-fitting issue.
Generally I follow following ways to handle it:

1. Add more features to training data. That includes deriving new features front the existing one.
2. Make a complex model.
3. Increase iterations.

Adding new training data only, I believe will not solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.